# Keydown event triggering classList.remove doesn't work if the key is pressed too many times in a row

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, keydown

I've implemented Wes Bos' Javascript 30 course's Drum Kit (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuN8qwZoego), but something is odd.

When a key is pressed, I add a class with `key.classList.add('playing')`, which transitions the key's div to a `border-color: yellow`, among other things, then removes the class again with `this.classList.remove('playing');` once triggered by a `transitionend` event.

It works fine, until I try to press a key many times really fast. Then, eventually the `.playing` class "sticks" to the div, ie, it's no longer removed.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if (!audio) return; //stop the function from running
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    key.classList.add('playing');
});

function removeTransition(e){
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform'){
        return;
    }
    this.classList.remove('playing');
}

const keys =  document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

```css
.drum-keys{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}

.key{
    display: flex;
    height: 70px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0, .2);
    font-style: bold;
    margin: 1em;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: 0.09s;
    text-align: center;
}

.key h1 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.key p {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.drum-keys li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.playing{
    border-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px grey;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<main class="site-content">
  
    <div class="playground-main">

        <ul class="drum-keys">
            <li>
                <div data-key="65" class="key"><h1>A</h1><p>CLAP</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div data-key="83" class="key"><h1>S</h1><p>HIHAT</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div data-key="68" class="key"><h1>D</h1><p>KICK</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div data-key="70" class="key"><h1>F</h1><p>OPENHAT</p></div>
            </li>             
            <li>
                <div data-key="71" class="key"><h1>G</h1><p>BOOM</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div data-key="72" class="key"><h1>H</h1><p>RIDE</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div data-key="74" class="key"><h1>J</h1><p>SNARE</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div data-key="75" class="key"><h1>K</h1><p>TOM</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div data-key="76" class="key"><h1>L</h1><p>TINK</p></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes with the fact that your biding to the keydown action, which, if you keep it pressed, it'll trigger multiple times than the transitionend. Because it happens multiple times, you end up with the class 'playing' and no transition taking place, thus the 'transitionend' event isn't fired anymore.

Change keyup to keydown and it should be fine.

You can easily see this if you console log in both functions like this and watch the console

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
/*     if (!audio) return; //stop the function from running
     *//*     audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play(); */
    key.classList.add('playing');
    console.log('keydown');
});

function removeTransition(e){
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform'){
        return;
    }

this.classList.remove('playing');
console.log('transition end');
}

const keys =  document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

If you're really keen to using 'keydown', I think you can get away with using 
`key.classList.toggle('playing')`